# Datatables Spring 4 Hibernate Tiles 3 Configuration Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datatable, dandelion

I am trying to implement [Datatables](http://datatables.net) spring in my project.

In `RoleController.java` file

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/masterRole")
public ModelAndView about() {
    RoleDAO dao = new RoleDAOImpl();
    List<Role> list = dao.list();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("list",list);
    model.setViewName("roleTile");
    return model;
     }
}
```

In `tiles.xml` file

```
  <definition name="roleTile" extends="base.definition" >
    <put-attribute name="title" value="DAM Role Master" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/viewRole.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menuselection" value="master" />
</definition>
```

In `viewRole.jsp` file

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>

 <datatables:table id="roles" data="${list}" row="role" cssClass="table table-striped">
<datatables:column title="Id">
    <c:out value="${role.roleId}"></c:out>
</datatables:column>
<datatables:column title="Role">
    <c:out value="${role.role}"></c:out>
</datatables:column>
 </datatables:table>
```

I am getting following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.configuration.ConfigurationStore.getPrototype(ConfigurationStore.java:82)
>   at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.configuration.TableConfiguration.getInstance(TableConfiguration.java:117)
>       at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.html.HtmlTable.(HtmlTable.java:76)
>       at com.github.dandelion.datatables.jsp.tag.TableTag.doStartTag(TableTag.java:91)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.viewRole_jsp._jspService(viewRole_jsp.java:78)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:535)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:638)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:632)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
>       at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
>       at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f4(layout_jsp.java:222)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:95)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
>       at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
>       at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

I am new to Datatables. Please help me.

Links are also invited for Datatbles step by step integration with Spring 4 with hibernate and tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says configuration is missing in `web.xml` for [datatables](http://datatables.net)

**Step 1:** In `web.xml`

```
<!-- Dandelion-Datatables servlet definition -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.servlet.DatatablesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/datatablesController/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion servlet definition and mapping -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Dandelion filter definition and mapping -->
 <filter>
   <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Step 2:** Add Required jar files

commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar
dandelion-core-0.10.0.jar
datatables-core-0.10.0.jar
datatables-jsp-0.10.0.jar
datatables-servlet2-0.9.3.jar
ehcache-core-2.6.9.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
json-simple-1.1.1.jar
jstl-api.jar
jstl-impl.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar

**Other jars:** Spring jars + tiles jars + hibernate jars

**Note:** I mensioned jars as per my project needs, you can add jars as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may come from the lack of some declarations in your `web.xml`. Already reported in the [forum](http://dandelion-forum.48353.x6.nabble.com/Need-help-Migrating-to-Datatables-0-10-0-td1377.html) and a fix will be available in the v0.10.1 to warn users about those missing declarations.

Just one note about the **datatables-servlet2** extra. 
Since the v0.10.0, it doesn't exist any longer. So I suggest you to remove it and avoid possible dependency issues with both 0.9.3 and 0.10.0.

The new declaration in `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<!-- Dandelion-Datatables filter used for basic export -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The [export section](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/export/) of the documentation has been updated to reflect the last changes.